# VBA MS Access 2010 How to call a Subroutine of an Object?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, subroutine

I've been trying to create a Subroutine in VBA for my Access application:

```
Public Sub addProduct(ByRef Product As Product, AsFoo As Integer, Optional Mutual As Boolean = True)
    Products.Add (Product)

    If (Mutual) Then
        Select Case AsFoo
            Case 0
                Product.setProjectmanager = Me
            Case 1
                Product.setVIP1 = Me
            Case 2
                Product.setVIP2 = Me
            Case 11
                Product.setVIP1A = Me
            Case 22
                Product.setVIP2A = Me
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

That one should just add the given Product to a Collection of Products and set the reference to the User reference, if Mutual is true.

That one should work... the problem is that I don't know how to call that
my current try is:

```
User.addProduct(Product, 0, True)
```

But the IDE wants to have a = at the end so I thought that would work:

```
User.addProduct(Product, 0, True) = Product
```

But that causes a Compile Error: 
`Expected function or Variable`

Comment: You need to declare as public function: public sub doesn't return values or objects.

Comment: But i dont want to return something, it should just add that Product to that Collection of the User. Is there a way to achive this?

Comment: Don't you need to use `Set` when assigning `Product.setProjectmanager = Me` because `Me` is an object?

Comment: Also, @KimGysen mentioned you need a function to return a value, but `User.addProduct(Product, 0, True) = Product` looks like you mean `Product = User.addProduct(Product, 0, True)`...?

Comment: @Graffi 1st uhmm yes i think so, thanks for that one. and 2nd no actualy i want the first line: User.addProduct(Product, 0, True)  but then i get an error that says that a = is expected und die IDE tells me to type Product... witch wont work...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I gave it a try below...

Comment: Just a question: since you use Access, couldn't you contain these data in a many-to-many related (associate) table? Just asking, I don't know what you need it for so it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @Gaffi; yeah you're right indeed. I thought to write a reply, because it could have been too long for commenting. Thanks for the notification anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling that line with:

`User.addProduct Product, 0, True`

or

`Call User.addProduct(Product, 0, True)`

Removing the `()` or using the `Call` keyword should work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do, but if it is adding class instances to a collection, I propose something like this:

```
Sub Main_sub()

dim colProduct as Collection 
dim cProduct as clsProduct
dim asFoo as integer    
dim Mutual as boolean


set colProduct = new collection
set cProduct = new clsproduct

asFoo = ? 'Define
Mutual = ? 'Define

'if the AddProduct function resides in the clsProduct class: 
set cProduct = cproduct.AddProduct(cProduct, asFoo, Mutual)
colProduct.add cProduct

set cProduct = nothing
set colProduct = nothing

end sub
```

And for private Product class properties Projectmanager, VIP1, VIP2, VIP1A,VIP2A

```
Public function addProduct(cProduct as clsProduct, AsFoo As Integer, Optional Mutual As Boolean) as cProduct

            If (Mutual) Then 
                Select Case AsFoo 
                Case 0 
                    cProduct.Projectmanager = Me 
                Case 1 
                    cProduct.VIP1 = Me 
                Case 2 
                    cProduct.VIP2 = Me 
                Case 11 
                    cProduct.VIP1A = Me 
                Case 22 
                    cProduct.VIP2A = Me 
                End Select 
            End If
set addProduct = cProduct
End Sub
```

You declare properties in a class module this way:

```
Private pVIP1 as <Type>
```

And getters / setters:

```
Public Property Get VIP1() As <Type>
    VIP1 = pVIP1
End Property

Public Property Let VIP1(tVIP1 As <Type>)
    pVIP1 = tVIP1
End Property
```

If the type is an object, you need to use SET instead of LET.

```
Public Property SET VIP1(tVIP1 As <Type>)
    SET pVIP1 = tVIP1
End Property
```

Maybe I've got your intentions wrong, because I don't see the purpose of adding Me to each of the cases. But this was the best I could come up with.

Comment: I left out a loop to add multiple class object instances in the collection.

Comment: Ok, in your case, the Collection is called "USER".

Comment: Wow, Thanks, that helps me a lot, i just get used to VBA, my java experience dosent quite help ^^